# R - CSV to ts for daily data

Tags: r

Just starting with R, and I am not managing to get my CSV/dataframe into a timeseries the way I need to. I have tried all related explanations I could find.

**Example of the raw data:**

```
date,count
2017-01-01,92
2017-01-02,606
2017-01-03,514
2017-01-04,377
2017-01-05,285
2017-01-06,250
2017-01-07,465
2017-01-08,64
```

I need a timeseries where each day like in the date column above fits with the sold count in the count column.

**Example of expected output:** (At least thats what I understood a daily timeseries should look like.. correct me if I'm, wrong)

```
2017-01-01  2017-01-02  2017-01-03
92          606         514
```

I tried loading this into R in many different ways, like:

```
 sold_raw.df=read.csv(file="Daily_sold_all_clients_2017_2018.csv", head=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

or

```
df <- read.csv("sold.csv", header=TRUE, row.names="date")
```

And then tried transforming them to a ts (also xts, also did not work, even though i need a ts for the tutorial i am doing)

```
x=ts(df)
```

or;

```
xts(df, order.by=as.Date(rownames(df),"%m/%d/%Y"))
```

this gives error:

```
Error in xts(df, order.by = as.Date(rownames(df), "%m/%d/%Y")) : 
  'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'
```

and:

```
ts.dat <- ts(data=df$count, start = 1, frequency = 365)
```

and:

```
> ts(df, order.by=as.Date(rownames(df),"%m-%d-%Y"))
Error in ts(df, order.by = as.Date(rownames(df), "%m-%d-%Y")) : 
  unused argument (order.by = as.Date(rownames(df), "%m-%d-%Y"))
```

None of these lines gave me the output I needed. Can anyone give me some direction on how to read in a csv with dates and counts and to transofrm it to a timeseries?

Comment: Could you add sample output and expected output and `dput(dataframe)`?

Comment: What is the output of `rownames(df)` ?

Comment: `[1] "2017-01-01" "2017-01-02" "2017-01-03" "2017-01-04" "2017-01-05" "2017-01-06" "2017-01-07" "2017-01-08" "2017-01-09" "2017-01-10" "2017-01-11" "2017-01-12"
 [13] "2017-01-13" "2017-01-14" "2017-01-15" "2017-01-16" "2017-01-17" "2017-01-18" "2017-01-19" "2017-01-20" "2017-01-21" "2017-01-22" "2017-01-23" "2017-01-24"
 `

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion of @Dave2e of using `"%Y-%m-%d"` ?

Comment: What is the error of using `ts`? You didn't show!

Comment: I added that as an edit in the bottom of the main question @TeeKea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are you are using a different date format from the one shown in your dataset. Try this:

```
xts(df, order.by=as.Date(rownames(df),"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Or, using `ts`:

```
ts.dat <- ts(df, start = 1, frequency = 365) 
row.names(ts.dat) <- rownames(df)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, now, can I also make this a regular timeseries ts in the same format?

Comment: That each count has the corresponding date. How can I get exactly the output of your answer, but then for a ts instead of xts?